# Replace Buttons in QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I started using Qt Creator some time ago and I managed to create my first GUI application by coding. However I don't like the standard buttons so I created one in designer mode but I can't figure out how to replace the old buttons with the one I created. Can someone give me a hint on how to do that?Thanks in advance!Here's my calculator application output : [calculator](http://oi57.tinypic.com/2zfvr87.jpg)

Comment: style sheet is the best approach. See this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Whatever properties you changed in designer mode to create your own button, you can take those change on your old buttons, if the old buttons are created in ui form (in designer).
2. Agree with the comment, if all you alter on buttons are about appearance, you can apply style sheet to all your buttons on calculator throught:

   QPushButton#buttonObjectName
   {
       border: none;
       border-radius: 0;
       background...
   }

or

```
QWidget#CalculatorObjectName QPushButton // this applies style to all button on calculator
{
}
```

1. (Not suggested) subclass QPushButton, overwrite what every protected functions you want to alter, and promote QPushButtons in your designer to your subclass name. i see no necessary in such solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!Well,where should I make these changes?I must include some library? Cause in my calculator.cpp file I can't,neither in the main.cpp. And all I did was coding,I didn't got into the designer mode,so the buttons are standard as I said. All I did was change they color through setstylesheet.

Comment: If you simply want to create "what you create in designer mode" in your code, you can copy the ui-generated code: compile a ui form file (say widget.ui) that contains your ideal button, this generates a header file named "ui_widget.h" or similar file, in the "setupUi()" method of this generated header file, you can get how Qt designer create your button, and you can refer it when creating buttons pragmatically.

Comment: The answer above are different solutions, they are not step by step. So can you specify which one you prefer to apply? besides, no additional libraries are required for your requirement.